# ¿Podemos mejorar las definiciones de las etiquetas "solicitud de ..."?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, preguntas

Hay una categoría de preguntas que solicitan un término o una expresión, ya sea para traducir de otro idioma, o para expresar una idea o un concepto que uno tiene en la cabeza.

1. Traducción: Es muy difícil ayudar al que hace la pregunta (es decir, al OP) si la pregunta no indica *cuál* de las acepciones, en *cuál* de los usos, se está solicitando el término o expresión.
2. Un concepto en la cabeza: También es muy difícil ayudar al OP si la pregunta no nos da una idea clara de lo que la palabra o expresión debe lograr en la frase.  (En este caso además de la frase ejemplar, también hay que dar el contexto en que vendría la frase.)

Por lo tanto propongo que mejoremos la definición de las etiquetas de [solicitud-de-término](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%c3%a9rmino) y [solicitud-de-modismo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-modismo).

Ejemplo de una pregunta reciente que no incluye un ejemplo: [¿Existe una traducción para “lifehack” en español?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23251/9385)

Ahora, un ejemplo de lo que mejoraría la pregunta:

> Llevo tiempo buscando un ______________ para resolver tal problema.  (traducción de *lifehack*)

Así el OP me ayudaría a ayudarlo.

Ahorita esto es lo que tenemos en la [definición de la etiqueta *solicitud de término*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/tags/solicitud-de-t%C3%A9rmino/info):

> Preguntas en las que se busca una palabra o frase en español dando su definición o explicación. || Looking for a Spanish word or phrase by submitting a definition or explanation.

En comparación, la definición de la etiqueta *single-word-requests* en English Language & Usage:

> This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead ...

Comment: Me parece buena idea, sin que por ello considere siempre necesario solicitar un ejemplo. Hay veces en que sin el ejemplo ya está claro.

Comment: @walen - ¿Por favor, lo pones en una respuesta?

Comment: @fedorqui - ¿Desarrollas un poco más tu idea en una respuesta, por favor?  La verdad, no entendí muy bien tu primera frase.  Con respecto a la segunda, ¿podrías dar un par de ejemplos?

Comment: Digo que no considero que sea necesario poner un ejemplo en todos los casos. Mirando preguntas con [esta etiqueta y también traducción](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solicitud-de-t%C3%A9rmino+traducci%C3%B3n) veo [casos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22299/1674). Tal y como comenta @walen, [editar wikis de etiquetas](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) es algo que puedes hacer tú mismo, ya sea directamente o sugiriendo una modificación. No creo que sea necesario más debate, porque no mucha más gente nos leerá :)